# Getting "Unable to find DB driver for sqlite3" when trying to start c-lightning node

Tags: core-lightning, database

Hey I just started receiving this message for my c-lightning node when try to start it.

```
Unable to find DB driver for sqlite3:///root/.lightning/bitcoin/lightningd.sqlite3
```

It started happening after I did `apt-get update/upgrade`.

I've googled but can't find anything about it and I got no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely this is due to a mismatch between the sqlite3 version that c-lightining was compiled with and the version your OS currently has installed. With the recently release v0.10
2, c-lightining now accepts a far wider range of library versions, so upgrading should address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the C-lightning node to start again after reinstalling/replacing the binaries.